# dict of dict displays a list after apply

Tags: python, json, pandas, dictionary, apply

I've got one DataFrame, like this one :

```
import pandas pd

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"name":["Spot1","Spot2"],2020:[{"product1":20.3,"product2":.93},{"product1":67,"product2":678}],2019:[{"product1":28,"product2":1003},{"product1":267,"product2":28}]})

    name                    2020                                  2019
0   Spot1   {'product1': 20.3, 'product2': 0.93}    {'product1': 28, 'product2': 1003}
1   Spot2   {'product1': 67, 'product2': 678}   {'product1': 267, 'product2': 28}
```

My goal is to concatenate the columns refering to a year to have this type of structure in a json :

```
    name                                        chronology
0   Spot1   {'2020':{'product1': 20.3, 'product2': 0.93}, '2019':{'product1': 28, 'product2': 1003}}
1   Spot2   {'2020':{'product1': 67, 'product2': 678},  '2019':{'product1': 267, 'product2': 28}}
```

So I wrote a function :

```
def all_timeline(x):
    dic = {str(i):x[i] for i in range(2020,2018,-1)}
    return dic
```

And then used it with an apply after a groupby :

```
after_gb=df.groupby(by="name").apply(all_timeline).reset_index()
after_gb.rename(columns={0:"chronology"}, inplace=True)

name    chronology
0   Spot1   {'2020': [{'product1': 20.3, 'product2': 0.93}...
1   Spot2   {'2020': [{'product1': 67, 'product2': 678}], .
```

Instead of dict inside a dict, I've got a dict with lists... I saw this error after a to_json export, that displays :

```
{
"name":{"0":"Spot1",
        "1":"Spot2"},
"chronology":{
    "0":{
        "2020":{"1":{"product1":20.3,"product2":0.93}},
        "2019":{"1":{"product1":28,"product2":1003}}},
    "1":{
        "2020":{"1":{"product1":67,"product2":678}},
        "2019":{"1":{"product1":267,"product2":28}}}}
}
```

What did I miss ?

Comment: I don't see a list in the JSON that you showed. There's no `[` or `]` in it.

Comment: Are you sure ? Juste redid after_gb=df.groupby(by="name").apply(all_timeline).reset_index()
after_gb.rename(columns={0:"chronology"}, inplace=True)

after_gb and it showed a list after "2020"

Comment: The content from the `to_json` export shows no list after "2020". In what's apparently printed to the Python terminal, there is a `[` after `'2020'`, which *may* indicate a list, or it may just be misleading. The JSON that you've shown, though, has no list at all.

Comment: My bad ! But after making the answer, I've got a proper dict in a dict : {"2020": {"product":1, etc}... No list anymore !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One Way:

```
df = df.set_index('name')
df = df.apply(lambda x: {f'{col}':x[col] for col in df.columns}, 1).reset_index(name = 'chronology')
```

Comment: Just tested, and it worked fine. I'll validate your answer in a few minutes. Thanks a lot !